# How to get a thinner font in options menu android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, menu

I've tried making a option menu in my activity, and I succeed. The problem now, is that the text style is bold, and I don't know how to make it normal. I tried setting textStyle, but it had no effect.

option_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:id="@+id/AppointmentItem"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_notifications_white_24dp"
    android:title="Appointments"/>
<item android:id="@+id/WeekItem"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_today_24dp"
    android:title="Week vooruit/achteruit"/>
<item android:id="@+id/LeerlingItem"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_24dp"
    android:title="Leerling veranderen"/>
<item android:id="@+id/InstelllingenItem"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_24dp"
    android:title="Instellingen"/>
<item android:id="@+id/OverItem"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_work_white_24dp"
    android:title="Over ons"/>
</menu>
```

How I create the options menu in my mainactivity.java

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.option_menu, menu); //your file name
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.AppointmentItem:
            return true;
        case R.id.WeekItem:
            getWeek();
            return true;
        case R.id.LeerlingItem:
            getLeerling();
            return true;
        case R.id.InstelllingenItem:
            getSettings();
            return true;
        case R.id.OverItem:
            getAbout();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

How it looks (first) and how I want it (last):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try digging into your current theme or style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by changing "TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title" to "TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle".

```
<style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle" parent="style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
</style>
```

Thanks to @Rotwang for advising me to check the styles.xml

Comment: @Rotwang mentioned you :)